# Postgresql insert into json does not work

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres user table with roles as `json`. I am struggling to insert data into it.
Roles looks like this:

> ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']

I tried several alternatives including this below, but nothing seems to work:

```sql
INSERT INTO myschema."user" (username, roles) 
VALUES ('brk', ARRAY['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']::json);
```

I do not get an error, explicitly as least.

Table defintions:

```
ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY'), ORM\Column(type: 'integer')
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE myschema."user" (
   id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
   username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
   roles JSON NOT NULL, 
   password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Comment: I think that last double quote after 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' looks suspicious to me.  I don't see a match for it anywhere.

Comment: You are right, but that was just me messing up the copy/paste. I fixed it above. It still does not work.

Comment: Please supply a usable [mre]. That is, the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) as well as the DML (`INSERT`) such that if we run it on dbfiddle.uk we'll get the same behaviour as you do.

Comment: You don't need to manually handle identifier sequences. Long time ago that was replaced with [`serial` types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) that make smallint/int/bigint column, then create and tie a sequence to them: `create table "user"(id serial primary key,...)`. More recently it's been replaced by [identity columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY): `create table "user"(id int generated by default as identity primary key, ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cast a `text[]` [*native array*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) type of `text` values, to a [`json` type value with a *json array*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-KEYS-ELEMENTS) ***in it***. That unfortunately won't work because there's no implicit cast defined out of the box, but you can instead convert it with [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.9.2.2.1.1.1.1) function: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FI-D0yQk)

```
INSERT INTO myschema."user" (username, roles) 
VALUES ('brk', to_json(ARRAY['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']))
RETURNING *;
```

| username | roles |
| --- | --- |
| brk | ["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"] |

If you were looking for a `json` constant/literal syntax:

```
INSERT INTO myschema."user" (username, roles) 
VALUES ('brk', '["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"]')
RETURNING *;
```

And as long as the `roles` column is defined as `json` type, you don't need to explicitly add the `::json` cast.

Comment: Somehow it still does not work. No explicit errors. The table definition is automatically generated by Symfony Doctrine migration.

Comment: If the table definition you showed is how the table is really defined, then it's doomed to fail: the sequence isn't tied to the id, and the id isn't nullable. There's no default value for it, so an `insert` statement that omits the `id` column simply tries to insert a *`null`* there, which will be rejected. Something is probably catching and ignoring your errors, which is another problem. Could you try to run `alter table "user" alter column id set default nextval('user_id_seq');`?

Comment: `alter table myschema."user" alter column id set default nextval('user_id_seq');
alter table myschema."user" alter column password set default random()::text;`
Otherwise, whenever you skip the `not null`able columns, the query tries to insert a *`null`* there, which must fail. [Here's a demo showing the fix.](https://dbfiddle.uk/H5eHmF3D)

Comment: Ok, resolved. A sequence of misteps. First I did not correctly define the User entity. I should have included  ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY'),
        ORM\Column(type: 'integer'). I changed the table definition above . Then I was attempting to insert without including the password, which is required. As somehow my PgAdmin does not return errors I was in the dark. Only when I used the Postgres online editor you showed me I got the error and could correct it. Thank you very much.